# HikariCP poolName configuration for Slick 3.0

Tags: slick, hikaricp, typesafe

I am using the following typesafe configuration in application.conf for Slick 3.0. HikariCP is the default connection pool of Slick 3.0. I set the poolName as "primaryPool":

```
slick.dbs.primary= {
  driver="com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver$"
  db {
    url = "DB URL"
    driver = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    user = "myUser"
    password = "myPassword"
    poolName="primaryPool"
  }
}
```

From the HikariCP log, I saw 
*Before cleanup pool stats **db** (total=21, inUse=0, avail=21, waiting=0)*

The default connection pool name "db" is used but not what I expected **primaryPool**. I suspect the configuration format is not correct.

So my question is how to configure poolName in application.conf using Typesafe configuration?

Note: Because I will have several connection pools in my application, I hope particular pool name is logged to distinguish different pool.

Comment: Based on looking at http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.2/database.html, the pool name might need to go in a "properties" block?

Comment: I tried it but not worked. Based on the link, user / password should also be under "properties", but in my app, I put them under db directly without properties and it work. So I guess Slick wants particular configuration for HikariCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a workaround by setting poolName in my own code:

```
 val dbConfig = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]
 val poolName = dbConfig.config.getConfig("db").getString("poolName")
 dbConfig .db.source.asInstanceOf[HikariCPJdbcDataSource].ds.setPoolName(poolName)
```

It is not a good solution since I hard code HikariCPJdbcDataSource, but it can meet my requirement at least.

Still hope get the help how to configure poolName correctly in the application.conf.